# EF6 Does not generate foreign key association from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, foreign-key-relationship

**PROBLEM:**

I am trying to create a EF6 model using the database first approach. Simply speaking, I have 2 tables `tblUser` and `tblMilkMan` which have a foreign key relationship on the `UserID` column. But when I create a new EDMX diagram and add the 2 tables:

1. I dont see the relationship
2. No navigation properties are created

Please tell me what Im doing wrong!

**DB Schema:**

[image: ER Diagram]

**Table Scripts:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblMilkMan]
    (
      [RecordID] [INT] NOT NULL
                       IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      [UserID] [INT] NOT NULL ,
      [IsMyTurn] [BIT] NOT NULL ,
      [RoundRobinOrder] [INT] NOT NULL
    )
ON  [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblMilkMan] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_tblMilkMan] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ([RecordID]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblMilkMan] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK__MilkMan__User__UserID] FOREIGN KEY ([UserID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[tblUser] ([UserID]) ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblUser]
    (
      [UserID] [INT] NOT NULL
                     IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      [LogonName] [VARCHAR](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_CI_AS
                                NOT NULL ,
      [Client] [CHAR](4) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_CI_AS
                         NOT NULL ,
      [Password] [VARCHAR](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_CI_AS
                               NOT NULL ,
      [PasswordExpires] [DATETIME] NULL ,
      [PasswordExpiresAfter] [INT] NOT NULL
                                   CONSTRAINT [DF_tblUser_PasswordExpiresAfter] DEFAULT ( 9999 ) ,
      [FirstName] [VARCHAR](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_CI_AS
                                NOT NULL ,
      [LastName] [VARCHAR](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_CI_AS
                               NOT NULL
    )
ON  [PRIMARY]
    WITH (
         DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW)

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblUser] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_tblUser] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ([UserID]) WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tblUser] ON [dbo].[tblUser] ([UserID]) WITH (FILLFACTOR=90, DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**EDMX Designer View:**

[image: VS2012 View]

**RELATED LINKS WHICH DIDNT HELP ME:**

- [Why doesn't EF 4 generate association for FK relation to column with
  unique index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511095/why-doesnt-ef-4-generate-association-for-fk-relation-to-column-with-unique-inde)
- [EF does not generate foreign key association from
  foreign key in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140426/ef-does-not-generate-foreign-key-association-from-foreign-key-in-table)

**ENVIRONMENT:**

- Visual Studio Ultimate 2012
- SQL Server 2014
- EF6
- Web API2

Comment: Might be the way you've pasted it, but you're creating the FK to tblUser before you create tblUser itself. So if you run that script it won't work. Are you sure FK is actually present on the database?

Comment: @JonEgerton yea, i just pasted it wrongly. My bad. The Tables and Keys exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the following line -

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tblUser] ON [dbo].[tblUser] ([UserID])
WITH (FILLFACTOR=90, DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

*I do not know the reason behind having Clustered and NonClustered indexes on same column. A common best practice is to create a Primary Key as Clustered Index. [(Source)](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/02/10/sql-server-primary-key-and-nonclustered-index-in-simple-words/)*

If you delete that **NONCLUSTERED INDEX**, it will see the relation in EDMX.

### How to delete it?

[image]

[image]