# EF6 not generating foreign key associations

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

My question is a follow-on to [EF6 Does not generate foreign key association from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824213/ef6-does-not-generate-foreign-key-association-from-database) but that answer was not sufficient to resolve my issue. I am using VS 2013 update 4/EF 6/SQL Server 2014.

In my case users represent linux accounts and have the following structure:

[image: Original DB Schema]

Where Accounts.Username and Groups.Name are primary keys and there are unique indexes on Accounts.UID and Groups.GID.  These are related through the GroupMembership table. EF creates:

[image: Original Model]

No associations.  Interestingly, when I change the Primary Keys:
[image: Updated DB Schema]

So that Accounts.UID and Groups.GID become the primary keys and Accounts.Username and Groups.Name have the unique indexes then I get:
[image: Updated Model]

It appears as though a many-many association will only be created for primary keys. If I try to create one manually in the designer, it won't use my GroupMembership table and I don't know enough to dig in past that.

Of course, I can work around my issue simply enough by using the updated schema but I am trying to improve my EF skills.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't surprise me at all if EF won't use varchar columns for keys...

Comment: Try increasing the size of the varchars to 255 and see if that changes anything.